# I need to X-unit test in ASP.NET Core Web API for authorizing API using cognito

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit

I am using OAuth 2.0 for authentication using aws cognito also using ASP.NET Core Web API for backend when I testing authorize API using the code shown here, but the test didn't pass and I got the following error:

> Expected: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult
> Actual:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.BadRequestObjectResult

Is this following approach correct, or do I need to mock authorize service for authorize API?

This is XUnit test:

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetCustomerOrders_ReturnsOk_WithCustomerOrders()
{
    // Arrange
    var mockOrders = new List<OrderViewModel>(); // Assuming Order is the type returned by _orderService.GetCustomerOrdersAsync()
    var accessToken = "eyJ";
    var userEmail = "testuser@example.com";

    var controllerContext = new ControllerContext
            {
                HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
                {
                    User = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userEmail)
                    }, "mock"))
                }
            };

    // Mock HttpContext to simulate authentication
    controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {accessToken}";

    _orderServiceMock.Setup(service => service.GetCustomerOrdersAsync(userEmail)).ReturnsAsync(mockOrders);

    // Mock the user authentication service
    _userServiceMock.Setup(auth => auth.GetAuthUserEmail(accessToken)).ReturnsAsync(userEmail);

    // Act
    var result = await _controller.GetCustomerOrders();

    // Assert
    var okResult = Assert.IsType<OkObjectResult>(result);
    var model = Assert.IsAssignableFrom<List<OrderViewModel>>(okResult.Value);

    Assert.Equal(mockOrders, model);
    _orderServiceMock.Verify(service => service.GetCustomerOrdersAsync(userEmail), Times.Once);
    _userServiceMock.Verify(auth => auth.GetAuthUserEmail(accessToken), Times.Once);
}
```

This is user auth service:

```
public class UserAuth : IUserAuth
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;

    public UserAuth(IConfiguration config)
    {
        _config = config;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetAuthUserEmail(string accessToken)
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var payload = new { AccessToken = accessToken };
                var jsonPayload = new StringContent(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(payload),
                                               null, "application/x-amz-json-1.1");

                // jsonPayload.Headers.Add("Content-Length", "1140");
                jsonPayload.Headers.Add("X-Amz-Target", "AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.GetUser");

                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                    {
                        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                        RequestUri = new Uri("https://cognito-idp.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/"),
                        Content = jsonPayload
                    };

                var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                UserData userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>(result);

                return userData.UserAttributes.FirstOrDefault(attr => attr.Name == "email")?.Value;
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        return "";
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet("GetCustomerOrders")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerOrders()
{
    try
    {
        var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
        var userEmail = await _userAuth.GetAuthUserEmail(accessToken);
        var orders = await _orderService.GetCustomerOrdersAsync(userEmail);

        return Ok(orders);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return InvalidBaseException(ex);
    }
}
```